# Swagger UI - Hide api-docs URL

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger-ui

I'm using swagger-ui **2.9.2** with **spring boot**.
Is there a way to hide **api-docs** URL using docket or the application properties file?

Thank you for your help.

[image]